How can I mount an Azure Storage blobContainer in a function app?
I'm trying to mount an Azure Storage Blob container to my function app, but I have been un-successful so far. I am using a Bicep template with a deployment script and everything goes through successfully, but when I go to list files in the mount path, I get a folder doesn't exist failure. Strangly enough, it does work when I use AzureFiles and connect to the fileshare on the same storage account.
This is my current deployment script (that doesn't work):
resource script 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2023-08-01' = {
  name: 'generatorScript'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {   
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}     
    }
  } 
  properties: { 
    azCliVersion: '2.59.0' 
    retentionInterval: 'PT1H' 
    arguments: '${resourceGroup().name}  ${functionApp.name} ${storageAccount.name}-share ${storageAccount.name} ${listKeys(storageAccount.id, '2021-09-01').keys[0].value}'   
    scriptContent: '''
      #!/bin/bash 
      if [[ "$(az webapp config storage-account list -g $1 -n $2)" == "[]" ]]; then   
        az webapp config storage-account add -g $1 -n $2 \   
        --custom-id $3 \   
        --storage-type AzureBlob \   
        --account-name $4 \   
        --share-name source \   
        --access-key $5 \   
        --mount-path /blog 
      fi'''   
  }  
  dependsOn: [ 
    roleAssignment 
  ]
}

And here is the deployment script that did work:
resource script 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2023-08-01' = {
  name: 'generatorScript'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {   
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}     
    }
  } 
  properties: { 
    azCliVersion: '2.59.0' 
    retentionInterval: 'PT1H' 
    arguments: '${resourceGroup().name}  ${functionApp.name} ${storageAccount.name}-share ${storageAccount.name} ${listKeys(storageAccount.id, '2021-09-01').keys[0].value}'   
    scriptContent: '''
      #!/bin/bash 
      if [[ "$(az webapp config storage-account list -g $1 -n $2)" == "[]" ]]; then   
        az webapp config storage-account add -g $1 -n $2 \   
        --custom-id $3 \   
        --storage-type AzureFiles \   
        --account-name $4 \   
        --share-name $4 \   
        --access-key $5 \   
        --mount-path /blog 
      fi'''   
  }  
  dependsOn: [ 
    roleAssignment 
  ]
}

I've also tried following (this tutorial in the portal and I arrive at a simliar result - works for the file share but not for the blob storage.

Azure Blob Storage mounts in read-only mode and lacks support for hierarchical directory structures, which may affect functionality


but when I go to list files in the mount path, I get a folder doesn't exist failure. Strangly enough, it does work when I use AzureFiles and connect to the fileshare on the same storage account.

According to this Document,
Azure blob storage

Azure Blob Storage uses a flat namespace. While it supports "virtual directories" through blob name prefixes (e.g., folder/file.txt), these are not real directories.
It does not use a file system protocol like SMB or NFS. Instead, blobs are accessed through APIs or SDKs.

Azure Files

Azure Files supports a traditional file system with both read and write capabilities, making it compatible with more scenarios.
It Provides SMB (Server Message Block) protocol support, making it suitable for mounting as a file system.

I would suggest using Azure Files, if your application requires write access or directory structures.
If you are mounted with azure blob storage you need verify container names and paths. Use SDKs or APIs for file operations instead of mounting when needed.
Reference:
List Blobs (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

It sound like you are saying that AzureBlobs can't be mounted like AzureFiles? If so, then why is AzureBlob even listed as a storage type that can be mounted?
